# R - How to fit a regression for log-normal with gamlss-package

Tags: r, regression, glm, data-fitting, gam

I’m trying to fit a log-normal-distribution to some data via the gamlss-function.
`y` is my dependant variable and `x` the explanatory variable.

As far as I understood the model `gamlss(y~x, family=LOGNO())` should be the approach.

But how is the formula to calculate my fitted values later with the estimated coefficients?
I mean something like in an ordinary linear regression where you have:

[image]

Even if I don't want to calculate the values by myself but use the `fitted()`-command I'm suprised why `y-fitted(fm)` is not the same as `residuals(fm)`.

But my biggest problem is, that in the help-file I read that the package also offers to *“model all the parameters of the distribution as functions of the explanatory variables”* and that’s exactly what I want to achieve.

So let's say I have the following:

[image]

And therefor:

[image]

So is there any way I can adapt the command to make sure `mu` and `sigma` are depending on `x`?
I guess I have to include `sigma.formula=~` in my command but I don't really know how and there is nothing like `mu.formula=~` at all.

Here is my code:

```
library(gamlss)

y<-c(1495418, 1684470, 1997120, 1901727, 2070008, 2213829, 2364602, 2333710, 2491570, 2540110, 2620947, 2761075, 2943475, 2854544)
x<-c(3932300, 4119100, 4354400, 4483752, 4585303, 4803234, 4989701, 5177605, 5380031, 5494672, 5606376, 5783627, 6015992, 6171564)

fm<-gamlss(y~x,familiy=LOGNO())
summary(fm)
fitted(fm)
residuals(fm)
y-fitted(fm)

fitted(fm,"mu")
fitted(fm,"sigma")
```

Comment: Maybe this similar topic on stats.stackexchange is helpful to you: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77752/how-to-check-if-my-data-fits-log-normal-distribution

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid it's not as my question is refering to the first interpretation Glen_b is talking about in his post and not the deeper described case.